# Query Xml File for Records using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Following is my xml file . I have to get Fields mentioned  for each page and for each Type in comma separated string. Please help in how to proceed using Linq

Example : If I want "Type = customFields" defined for "page1" , have to get output in comma separated
ProjectID,EmployeeID,EmployeeName,hasExpiration etc

```
<Pages>
 <Page Name="Page1" >
<Type TypeID="customfields">
  <Field>ProjectID</Field>
  <Field>EmployeeID</Field>
  <Field>EmployeeName</Field>
  <Field>HasExpiration</Field>
  <Field>EndDate</Field>
</Type>
<Type TypeID="Directfields">
  <Field>ProjectID</Field>
  <Field>EmployeeID</Field>
  <Field>EmployeeName</Field>
  <Field>HasExpiration</Field>
  <Field>EndDate</Field>
  <Field>IsInUpdateMode</Field>
  <Field>TimesheetSpendLimit</Field>
</Type>
 </Page>
  <Page Name="Page2" >
    <Type TypeID="customfields">
  <Field>ProjectID</Field>
  <Field>EmployeeID</Field>
  <Field>EmployeeName</Field>
  <Field>HasExpiration</Field>
  <Field>EndDate</Field>
  <Field>IsInUpdateMode</Field>
  <Field>TimesheetSpendLimit</Field>
</Type>
<Type TypeID="Directfields">
  <Field>ProjectID</Field>
  <Field>EmployeeID</Field>
  <Field>EmployeeName</Field>
  <Field>HasExpiration</Field>
  <Field>EndDate</Field>
  <Field>IsInUpdateMode</Field>
  <Field>TimesheetSpendLimit</Field>
</Type>
  </Page>
</Pages>
```

Comment: check this post, it may help:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-deserialize-xml-using-linq.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var Result = from a in element.Descendants("Page")
             from b in a.Descendants("Type")
             select new
             {
               Page = a.Attribute("Name").Value,
               Type = b.Attribute("TypeID").Value,
               Fields = String.Join(",", b.Elements("Field").Select(x => x.Value))
             };
foreach (var item in Result)
{
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Page = {0}:Type={1}:Fields:{2}", item.Page, item.Type, item.Fields));
}
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sGei6d)

Check my  [this blog article](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-deserialize-xml-using-linq.html) as well for more.