# how to fetch phone number from xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am having following xml response

```
   <participantpasscode>92793519</participantpasscode>
    <dialInNumber>
        <phoneType>FREE</phoneType>
        <formattedNumber>0808 1005145</formattedNumber>
        <displayName>United Kingdom Freefone: 0808 1005145</displayName>
        <rawNumber>08081005145</rawNumber>
        <country>GBR</country>
    </dialInNumber>
    <dialInNumber>
        <phoneType>NATR</phoneType>
        <formattedNumber>0844 5610081</formattedNumber>
        <displayName>United Kingdom Primary: 0844 5610081</displayName>
        <rawNumber>08445610081</rawNumber>
        <country>GBR</country>
    </dialInNumber>
    <createDate>2014-11-19T15:09:09.815Z</createDate>
```

on phone type I can find this dial in number is toll number or toll free number for eg if phone type is 'Free' then it is toll free number otherwise this is toll numbet. I want to write code in c# to fetch toll no and toll free no from this xml response.

Comment: I am not getting any approach!!

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422431/query-xml-file-for-records-using-linq

Comment: also check this fiddle:https://dotnetfiddle.net/2uKdd5

Comment: Linq is a good way to fetch them

Comment: @NituBansal LINQ is C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you will have to add a root element to your xml otherwise this solution may not work. If you really can't add it you can get around it by using an XMLText reader and setting the conformance level to fragment.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var children = doc["root"].ChildNodes;
foreach (XmlNode c in children)
{
    if (c.Name == "dialInNumber")
    {
        var type = c["phoneType"].InnerText;
        var number = c["rawNumber"].InnerText;
        //Do stuff with type and number
    }
}
```

Note that I've added a root element called root that's why on the third line I go into that element, other wise the doc.LoadXml method will throw an exception.