# How to get child element value in XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to access child element value in xml.

```
<Menus>
    <ParentMenu>
        <ParentName>Home</ParentName>
    </ParentMenu>
    <ParentMenu>
        <ParentName>Shop</ParentName>
        <SubMenus>
            <Submenu>
                <SubName>SHop1</SubName>
            </Submenu>
            <Submenu>
                <SubName>SHop2</SubName>
            </Submenu>
            <Submenu>
                <SubName>SHop3</SubName>
            </Submenu>
            <Submenu>
                <SubName>SHop4</SubName>
            </Submenu>
        </SubMenus>
    </ParentMenu>
    <ParentMenu>
        <ParentName>MegaMenu</ParentName>
    </ParentMenu>
</Menus>
```

There is my code

```
var menus = (from Parent in xdoc.Root.Descendants("ParentMenu")
             select new Menus
             {
                 ParentName = Parent.Descendants("ParentName").First().Value,
                 Submenus = (from sub in Parent.Descendants("SubMenus")
                                               .Descendants("Submenu")
                             select new SubMenus 
                             {
                                 SubName = sub.Descendants("SubName")
                                              .First().Value,
                             }).ToList()
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Please can you also post a relevant snippet of the Xml you are trying to parse?

Comment: <Menus>
  <ParentMenu>
    <ParentName>Home</ParentName>
  </ParentMenu>
  <ParentMenu>
    <ParentName>Shop</ParentName>
    <SubMenus>
      <Submenu>
      <SubName>SHop1</SubName>
      </Submenu>
      <Submenu>
      <SubName>SHop2</SubName>
      </Submenu>
      <Submenu>
      <SubName>SHop3</SubName>
      </Submenu>
      <Submenu>
      <SubName>SHop4</SubName>
      </Submenu>
    </SubMenus>
  </ParentMenu>
  <ParentMenu>
    <ParentName>MegaMenu</ParentName>
  </ParentMenu>

Comment: @DurgpalSingh what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Childnode name is not access

Comment: check this for reading xml using linq:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422431/query-xml-file-for-records-using-linq

Comment: This code seems to work well.  I'm not sure I see a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you appear to simply be deserializing the entire Xml Structure into a, I believe Xml Deserialization is a better strategy for what you are attempting:

Given the below DTO structures (noting also that `ParentMenu` items have no wrapper):

```
public class Submenu
{
    public string SubName { get; set; }
}
public class ParentMenu
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public List<Submenu> SubMenus { get; set; }
}
public class Menus
{
    [XmlElement("ParentMenu")]
    public List<ParentMenu> ParentMenus { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can then simply deserialize:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Menus));
using (var sr = new StringReader(xml)) // Or use TextReader if you are off file
{
    var result = (Menus)ser.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

If however you really want to do the above deserialization manually in Linq to Xml, this will work with the same DTO structure above:

```
var menus = (from Parent in xdoc.Root.Descendants("ParentMenu")
             select new ParentMenu
             {
                 ParentName = Parent.Descendants("ParentName").First().Value,
                 SubMenus = (from sub in Parent.Descendants("SubMenus")
                                               .Descendants("Submenu")
                             select new Submenu
                             {
                                 SubName = sub.Descendants("SubName")
                                              .First().Value,
                             }).ToList()
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: but i am using MVC 5 is it work in mvc?

Comment: Yes, deserialization will work for MVC too :) The update renames the DTO's in line - by convention, collection properties should be plural (end in "s") to convey intent to the next developer reading the code. When you `.Select` you are projecting a single item at a time.