# Converting XML to ASP.NET MVC model

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to XML.
The following xml is received as a string from a webservice

```
"<settings>   
  <calculator display="1" />
  <details display="1" />
  <charge display="1" />
  <features>
    <feature code="HAZ" description="CARGO" />
    <feature code="IDL" description="DELIVERY" />
    <feature code="LFT" description="TRUCK" />
    <feature code="NFY" description="CARRIER CHARGE" />
  </addons>
</settings>  "
```

And below are user-configuration which has a list as a property.

```
 public class UserConfiguration
 {
     public int calculator { get; set; }

     public int details { get; set; }

     public int charge { get; set; }

     public List<Accessorial> features { get; set; }
 }

 public class Accessorial
 {
     public string code { get; set; }

     public string description { get; set; }
 }
```

I have tried the following but the values are null;

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserConfiguration), new XmlRootAttribute("root"));
var objectValue = deserializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

I had also put `XmElement("calculator")` and so, on the properties according to some answers on stackoverflow but they also didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml

Comment: this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422431/query-xml-file-for-records-using-linq

Comment: What is the problem, what doesn't work

Comment: @mybirthname The objectValue is null after parsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below Contract with Attribute Programming:

```
[XmlRoot("settings")]
public class Settings
{
   [XmlElement("calculator")]
   public Calculator calculator { get; set; }

   [XmlArray("features")]
   [XmlArrayItem("feature")]
   public List<Feature> features {get; set; }
}

public class Calculator 
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string display { get; set; }
}
```