# How to loop through an xml with similar elements names and different attributes to get value at each node?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read the specific node values of an xml :

```
<dsobject handle="Document-27897" classname="Document" baseClassname="Document">
<props>
  <prop name="summary" type="10">2952239651</prop>
  <prop name="highest_version_used" type="1">1</prop>
  <prop name="routing_template_id" type="1" />
  <prop name="modified_date" type="4">Thu Jul 21 15:02:58 EDT 2011</prop>
  <prop name="locale" type="10">en</prop>
  <prop name="max_versions" type="1">4</prop>
  <prop name="canAddVersions" type="3">true</prop>
  <prop name="author" type="10"></prop>
  <prop name="title" type="10">806</prop>
  <prop name="create_date" type="4">Thu Jul 21 15:02:58 EDT 2011</prop>
  <prop name="description" type="11">SELF HELP (KVII) ASSOC-CITY CAPITAL</prop>
  <prop name="original_file_name" type="10">DOC20110721150230-853.pdf</prop>
  <prop name="webdav_title" type="10"></prop>
  <prop name="keywords" type="10"></prop>
  <prop name="add_as_draft" type="3">false</prop>
  <prop name="cfCopyID" type="10"></prop>
  <prop name="lastSynchronized" type="4" />
  <prop name="isPlaceholder" type="3">false</prop>
  <prop name="isRecord" type="3">false</prop>
  <prop name="rm_instance_handle" type="10" />
  <prop name="client_data" type="10"></prop>
  <prop name="copiedFrom" type="10"></prop>
  <prop name="cfSpecialWords" type="10"></prop>
  <prop name="autoMovePreferredVersion" type="3">true</prop>
  <prop name="size" type="1">1365070</prop>
  <prop name="isInteract" type="3">false</prop>
  <prop name="expiration_date" type="4" />
  <prop name="readyForDeclare" type="3">false</prop>
</props>
```

I need to get the value of specific elements namely :

```
<prop name="summary" type="10">2952239651</prop>
<prop name="description" type="11">SELF HELP (KVII) ASSOC-CITY CAPITAL</prop`>
<prop name="original_file_name" type="10">DOC20110721150230-853.pdf</prop>
```

This  the code I am using to get the value of the element with attribute name="summary", but I am not able to use the same query to get the other values(====>name="description, name="original_file_name)

```
var number = (from x in collection.Root.Descendants("dsobject") where x.Attribute("handle").Value.Contains("Document") select x.Element("props")).ToList();

 var vals = (from c in number where c.Element("prop").Attribute("name").Value == "summary" select c.Element("prop").Value).ToList();
```

Can someone lead me in the right direction to do this? Thanks

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422431/query-xml-file-for-records-using-linq

Answer (score 0):

If you know the elements exist then do

```
string summary = xdoc.Root.Element("props").Elements("prop").First(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "summary").Value;

string description = xdoc.Root.Element("prop").Elements("prop").First(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") = "description").Value;
```

and so on.

If there are several `props` elements and you want a list of e.g. `summary` values then use

```
List<string> summaries = xdoc.Root.Elements("props").Elements("prop").Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "summary").Select(s => s.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `System.Xml.Linq` you can do the following.

```
        var xmlFile = XDocument.Load("xmlpath");

        var propElements = xmlFile.Descendants("prop");
        var summaryProp = propElements.Where(e =>
            string.Compare(e.Attribute("name").Value, "summary"
            , StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        var summaryValue = summaryProp.Value;
```

The variable summaryValue will hold the value 2952239651.

This method assumes only one element will be named summary.

Update

Sorry - the following code can be used to retrieve the summary for multiple props:

```
        var xmlFile = XDocument.Load("xmlpath");

        var propElements = xmlFile.Descendants("prop");
        var summaryProp = propElements.Where(e =>
            string.Compare(e.Attribute("name").Value, "summary"
            , StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            .Select(prop => prop.Value).ToList();
```