# Xml parsing with attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

How to easily parse the xml response from a service. 
I want to deserialize this xml data to c# class. Please give me a solution.

```
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/SMIL21/Language">
<head>
    <meta name="updateLockInterval" content="20" />
    <meta name="lockId" content="EMK9KUpCkhGys3VrW8RCoQAH8NC7ELD1" />
    <meta name="lockSequenceToken" content="SvTvwTjjuTl+1aVegeyuEIAb50M=" />
    <meta name="lock" content="content" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</smil>
```

I also want the values of name and content attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query Xml File for Records using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422431/query-xml-file-for-records-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

You could have use the following

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
```

load your xml document to **xmlDoc**

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("**Load the required node**");
```

then using a for loop iterate through each nodes and get the data.

Comment: How can i get the values of attributes inside meta node? (eg:name="updateLockInterval" content="20")

Comment: your document looks like an Html document can you share that exact xml doc