# how to parse xml , linq c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

i am trying to load the xml file as below and read the value for each element but the Result count always = Zero , below my xml example with code

1 ) My xml is :

```
<ROOT xmlns="authenticateUser">
<PARTYCODE></PARTYCODE>
<VRETCODE>10</VRETCODE>
<PRETCODE>10</PRETCODE>
<VRETERR>Incorrect user name or password entered.</VRETERR>
</ROOT>
```

2 ) My Code is :

```
 XDocument Doc = XDocument.Parse(strFileData);
                    var Result = (from Root in Doc.Descendants("ROOT")
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      PARTYCODE = Root.Element("PARTYCODE").Value ?? string.Empty,
                                      VRETCODE = Root.Element("VRETCODE").Value ?? string.Empty,
                                      PRETCODE = Root.Element("PRETCODE").Value ?? string.Empty,
                                      VRETERR = Root.Element("VRETERR").Value ?? string.Empty,
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query Xml File for Records using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422431/query-xml-file-for-records-using-linq)

Comment: Nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROOT` and all child elements are in the namespace `authenticateUser`, thanks to the `xmlns="authenticateUser"` default namespace attribute.  So you need to query on on the the element local name plus the namespace name, which can be constructed using [`XName.Get(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299741%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    XDocument Doc = XDocument.Parse(strFileData);
    var Result = (from Root in Doc.Descendants(XName.Get("ROOT", "authenticateUser"))
                  select new
                  {
                      PARTYCODE = Root.Element(XName.Get("PARTYCODE", "authenticateUser")).Value ?? string.Empty,
                      VRETCODE = Root.Element(XName.Get("VRETCODE", "authenticateUser")).Value ?? string.Empty,
                      PRETCODE = Root.Element(XName.Get("PRETCODE", "authenticateUser")).Value ?? string.Empty,
                      VRETERR = Root.Element(XName.Get("VRETERR", "authenticateUser")).Value ?? string.Empty,
                  }).ToList();
```